# Is there any error in the try-catch exception handling below?

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, try-catch

I tried to handle an exception while a user is trying to login after being authenticated by firebase. But this try-catch is not working in my flutter project.

Can someone let me know where did i go wrong? I have attached my code below.

Thank you in advance.

```
class AuthService {
  //Creating an instance of firebase.
  final auth.FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User? _userFromFirebase(auth.User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return User(user.uid, user.email);
  }

  Stream<User?>? get user {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebase);
  }

  Future<User?> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    String email,
    String password,
  ) async {
    try {
      final credential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);

      return _userFromFirebase(credential.user);
    } on Exception catch (_, e) {
      //I want to display a toast message if the login fails here. 
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    return await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific as to why the `try` `catch` is not working? What should happen that doesn't? also I believe it should be `catch (e, _)` instead of `catch (_, e)`

Comment: I tried to handle any exceptions that may occur during the login process from firebase auth. And what i want to is to try to authenticate the with the "signInWithEmailAndPassword" method given by firebase. And if any exception occurs such as , wrong password, i want to return that message to the user using the catch. 

This is what i want to achieve. 

And btw, i tried changing `catch(e, _)`  instead of `catch(_, e)` but still doesn't make any difference. 

Thank you :)

Comment: ok, so I don't think you can show anything to the user from this method. I recommend you add a `rethrow` on the last line of the catch, and then where you call `signInWithEmailAndPassword` you can surround that with a try-catch again and on the catch use show a snackbar. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your try-catch block you are catching `Exception` types, but Firebase Authentication has its own exception type, `FirebaseAuthException`.

For possible error codes for this specific sign-in see [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithEmailAndPassword.html), but there are others as well.

Check the following code:

```
try {
  final credential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email, password: password);
  return _userFromFirebase(credential.user);
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  // here you will have the different error codes in `e.code`
  // for example `invalid-email` or `wrong-password`
}
```

It is up to you how do you handle these errors. You can return the error code for example and handle it from where you call this function (as h8moss suggested in comment).

And keep in mind that there are other possible reasons for a sign-in to fail than `FirebaseAuthException`. For example network connection can be down. So a more complete solution to catch other errors as well would be something like:

```
try {
  // sign in
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  // handle Firebase Authentication exceptions
} catch (e) {
  // handle other exceptions
}
```